# Soundcloud API Upload suddenly throwing code 422

Tags: php, soundcloud

Been using the PHP Soundcloud API for some time now, and it's been working fine. The code I use to create the track array is (and has always been):

```
$track = json_decode($client->post('tracks', array(
  'track[title]' => $title,
  'track[asset_data]' => $filename,
  'track[description]' => $desc,
  'track[genre]' => "Podcast",
  'track[artwork_data]' => $image
)));
```

And it's always been working just fine - until this morning, when I got this error message when uploading a track using my home-made PHP tool:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 422.' in /home/csicon/public_html/PodcastAuthor/lib/Soundcloud.php:943 Stack trace: #0 /home/csicon/public_html/PodcastAuthor/lib/Soundcloud.php(621): Services_Soundcloud->_request('https://api.sou...', Array) #1 /home/csicon/public_html/PodcastAuthor/2-publish.php(52): Services_Soundcloud->post('tracks', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/csicon/public_html/PodcastAuthor/lib/Soundcloud.php on line 943

Now, I'm no newb, and know what HTTP code 422 is all about, so I checked the contents of $title, $filename, $desc and $image. They are, in order:

```
Geekdays #274: 2015-11-17

@/home/csicon/public_html/PodcastAuthor/uploads/g274.mp3

Snowden, the FBI and the Oxford Dictionary are getting blamed for things that they may or may not have done. Also; the air you're breathing might be killing you. This, and so much more, on today's episode of Geekdays.

@/home/csicon/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/geekdays-600x600.png
```

All paths (to the mp3 and the image) check out, there's nothing wonky in the character set being used, and it's all worked before. What might have happened here? I'm stumped.

**UPDATE!** Turns out my webhost has upgraded their PHP environment from 5.4 to 5.6, and this is what broke it. What's changed between 5.4 and 5.6 that might have caused this, in that case?

Comment: Is there any documentation for php?On soundcloud they only have python,ruby and js.

Comment: I'm using the [API Wrapper for SoundCloud](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) written in PHP. Nothing's changed in my code, however, it worked yesterday evening when I uploaded one track and then doesn't work today when I'm uploading another track.

Comment: CAn you show the $track variable?After json_decode

Comment: Unfortunately not, the 422 comes from the $client->post part of that line. However, the array that I'm sending into it looks like this:

Comment: array(5) { ["track[title]"]=> string(25) "Geekdays #274: 2015-11-17" ["track[asset_data]"]=> string(56) "@/home/csicon/public_html/PodcastAuthor/uploads/g274.mp3" ["track[description]"]=> string(181) "Edward Snowden, The Oxford Dictionary and even the FBI. All of them are getting blamed for things that they may or may not have done. Also, do you think that's air you're breathing?" ["track[genre]"]=> string(7) "Podcast" ["track[artwork_data]"]=> string(73) "@/home/csicon/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/geekdays-600x600.png" }

Comment: I think that single quote in $desc is messing things up.You might have magic quotes in php.ini which adds an escape / before that quote,so it messes the structure.One easy way to test it is to remove the quote manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95331/discussion-between-breki-tomasson-and-mihai).

Answer (score 0):

> Turns out my webhost has upgraded their PHP environment from 5.4 to 5.6, and this is what broke it. What's changed between 5.4 and 5.6 that might have caused this, in that case?

How cURL file uploads are handled has changed.

`CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` is set to `true` by default from PHP 5.6 on, and that means file uploads are not possible any more using the `@`-file path syntax, but `CURLFile` should be used for file uploads instead.

Try setting `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to `false`, using the [`setCurlOptions`](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/blob/master/Services/Soundcloud.php#L517) method.

Comment: Thanks. I'd already upgraded to the curl-file branch, but it didn't help. Do I need to build my variables/array differently somehow?

Comment: Yeah, didn't help either, strangely. Finally worked when I went for [another fork of the curl-file branch](https://github.com/sebdesign/php-soundcloud/tree/curl-file) of the original, however! Still trying to figure out what's different between the two that caused it to start working ...

Answer (score 0):

Magically started working when I changed to the [sebdesign/php-soundcloud](https://github.com/sebdesign/php-soundcloud/tree/curl-file) version of the curl-file branch. Not sure why the "normal" curl-file branch didn't work, however.